# Проблемы с организацией sql запроса

Tags: php, sql

Доброго времени суток! Нет большого опыта работы с sql, но основы знаю. Практика показала что основ не достаточно и не могу найти решения (может плохо искал, может не хватает извилин...). Суть вопроса следующая: есть формирование sql запроса:

```
$sql = "select usr.id, usr.$this->attributeNameUser as $this->attributeNameUser, msg.cnt as cnt_mess ";
$sql .= "from $this->userTableName as usr ";
$sql .= "inner join ";
$sql .= "(select from_id, count(id) as cnt from $table_name where status = 1 and whom_id = :user_id GROUP by from_id) as msg ";
$sql .= "ON msg.from_id = usr.id ";
$sql .= " where usr.id != :user_id ";
```

Здесь используются 2 таблицы: user и message. Данный запрос возвращает количество новых сообщений от пользователей (status = 1). Если убрать это условие - он вернёт мне все сообщения как новые... Вопрос: возможно ли исправить запрос, что бы он брал пользователей с которыми у меня есть переписка, а в свойство cnt заносил значения со статусом 1??

Comment: это запрос из модуля реализации сообщений для фреймворка yii2, поэтому разбить на несколько разных запросов и формировать данные крайне тяжело... Нужно ковырять сам модуль чего делать крайне не хочеться...

Comment: Не так всё просто, если бы было решение таким простым - сделал бы сам)) Но спасибо за помощь! Суть в том, что если поставить left join мне покажуться **ВСЕ** пользователи, а не те с которыми я веду переписку...

Comment: Как развитие мысли: Если есть status = 1, то мне возвращается количество новых сообщений от пользователя... Если нет status = 1, то мне возвращаются все пользователи с которыми я вел переписку с общим количеством сообщений! Как связать так, что бы передавались все пользователи и считались только сообщения от них со status = 1???

Comment: Вы просто гений! Вы мне просто неимоверно помогли!! Спасибо Вам большое!!!

Comment: Mike не могли бы Вы сделать Ваш комментарий ответом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы оставить все записи возвращаемые подзапросом следует как вы и делали убрать условие отбора status=1 и посчитать количество записей со статусом 1 с помощью `sum(case when status=1 then 1 else 0 end)` или, если статус может принимать только два значения 0 и 1 то просто `sum(status)`.